# The purpose of the splitting lemma for $\mathsf{SF(\Sigma^*})$

Tags: regular-languages

We've definied the splitting lemma for starfree languages as follows:
Let $L \in \mathsf{SF}(\Sigma^*)$ and $A, B \subseteq \Sigma$ with $A \cap B = \emptyset$. Then it holds true that for $K_i, L_i \in \mathsf{SF}(B^*)$: $$L \cap B^* A B^*= \bigcup_{\text{finite}} K_iAL_i$$

I can not see why this is useful by any means. At first, I thought that we might use this to "translate" some $L$ to its starfree equivalent, but we use $L \in \mathsf{SF}(\Sigma^*)$ as a precondition for the lemma, and furthermore, we don't even get a starfree representation of $L$ through this. So what do we use this for?

Comment: "The proofs are either based on a congruence lemma
established for first-order logic in Section 10.1, or they are based on a splitting lemma established for star-free languages in Section 3.1." (Diekert and Gastin, [First-order definable languages](https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.144.3776&rep=rep1&type=pdf))